# Como fazer Download de imagens com PHP

Tags: php, imagem, url, google, download

Galera estou com uma duvida urgente.

Quero conseguir fazer o downloads de imagens utilizando php, essas URL de imagens estão em uma planilha do google docs, consegui fazer a conexao, e consegui fazer um codigo que faça o download, porem o arquivo que me veem e diferente doque eu esperava:

URl da imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo que estou utilizando:

```
<?php
$url_do_arquivo = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ-J4JhsR1TFU9iKPJFPOE77U2VqYECdGp9eiP1_XRbUaLEoZu8PjrdODrxxSSsl7mBQRks3T_Y9WTy/pub?output=csv";
if (($identificador = fopen($url_do_arquivo, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
echo '<pre>';

while (($linha_do_arquivo = fgetcsv($identificador, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {


    printf("%-10s %-19s  <br />",  $linha_do_arquivo[1], $linha_do_arquivo[3]);

    file_put_contents($linha_do_arquivo[1],file_get_contents($linha_do_arquivo[3]));
}
echo '</pre>';

fclose($identificador);
} else {


echo 'Não foi possível abrir o arquivo';
}
```

Realmente está fazendo o download, porem oque e um arquivo de texto da url com oque se eu não me engano e uma especie de CSS da imagem, porem preciso da imagem em si.

Como resolver isso ?